# Why array does not contain AsReadOnly method?

Tags: c#, .net

`List` has instance method `AsReadOnly`:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var readOnlyList = list.AsReadOnly();
```

That creates `ReadOnlyCollection`:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnly()
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>((IList<T>) this);
}
```

But array has only static method for this:

```
var array = new int[] { };
var readOnlyArray = Array.AsReadOnly(array);
```

Doing the same:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnly<T>(T[] array)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (array));
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>((IList<T>) array);
}
```

What the reason to declare different API for equal methods?

Comment: `List<T>` and `ReadonlyCollection<T>` are both `IList<T>`. `Array.AsReadOnly` converts the array to a generic, this is a completely different type (`Array` implements `IList` but not `IList<T>`). So basically it is the difference between casting to a compatible type versus an incompatible one.

Comment: @RonBeyer - not following what you're trying to say here. Any particular array (remember, `Array` itself is an abstract type) *does* implement the `IList<T>` generic interface. The cast shown in the last line of code in the question *is* a cast and *not* a conversion.

Comment: @RonBeyer or to put it another way -  create an empty console application and just add the line `IList<string> args2 = args;` into `Main`. You'll find that compiles to just `ldarg.0` followed by `stloc.0`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Correct. To be very pedantic, your "Any particular array" should be "Any particular one-dimensional (zero-indexed) array". Note that a concrete array type like `SomeType[,]` does not even implement generic `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. (However, confusingly, it implements non-generic `IList`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is an abstract class and was created before generics was a thing in .NET. If generics had always been a thing this class would almost certainly have been `Array<T>` rather than `Array`.

However, we can't go back and change a fundamental base class. As such, we cannot add an *instance* method to *this* class that is strongly typed to the specific type `T` of the array.

Hence, it's added as a static method instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a long comment, not an answer to your question.

It is easy enough to create an extension method that gives you the syntax you want:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
  public static ReadOnlyCollection<TEntry> AsReadOnly<TEntry>(this IList<TEntry> li)
    => new ReadOnlyCollection<TEntry>(li);
}
```

With that, you can do `yourArray.AsReadOnly()`. This has the benefit that it also works for all other types that happen to implement `IList<>`.

If you do not want that, of course you can extend *only* arrays:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
  public static ReadOnlyCollection<TEntry> AsReadOnly<TEntry>(this TEntry[] arr)
    => Array.AsReadOnly(arr);
}
```

There is no reason to have both methods.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` in it's nature is read only, i.e. you can't add an item to it and grow it. That is the reason we have no `AsReadOnly`  method like `IList`.

Comment: A `ReadOnlyCollection` doesn't allow any individual *element* of the collection to be replaced. Elements are trivial to reassign in an array. So the array, by itself, only offers half of the guarantees that a `ReadOnlyCollection` does.